# issue in printing out associative array using foreach in blade

Tags: laravel, loops, associative-array, laravel-blade

I have written a simple code to print out elements of associative array but it is in a conditional loop and although i think foreach is written correctly. it doesnt work. the foreach loop is using a variable which was passed by routes.

```
return view('results')
    ->with('name', $name)
    ->with('state', $state)
    ->with('pms', $pms)
    ->with('hasresult', $hasresult)
    ->with('err', $err)
    ->with('errNoEntries', $errNoEntries);
```

The code is written below:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Search Results
@endsection

@section('content')

    <h2>Australian Prime Ministers</h2>

    @if ($errNoEntries) {{-- meaning the data was entered incorrectly --}}
        <p class='alert'>{{$err}}</p>
    @elseif (!$hasresult)
        <p class='alert'>No Results found</p>
    @else
        <table class="bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($pms as $pm) 
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$pm['index']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$pm['name']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$pm['from']}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    @endif

    <form method="post" action="searchresult">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <table>
            <tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Year: </td><td><input type="text" name="year"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>State: </td><td><input type="text" name="state"></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" value="Search">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset"></td></tr>
         <table>
     </form>

@endsection
```

Comment: Which error given? and what is the output of $err ?

Comment: ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/ubuntu/workspace/WebAppDev/Week4/assoc-laravel/resources/views/results.blade.php)

Comment: err is a string type variable. the top if elseif work fine and error checking works, its just the else bit specifically the printing of the associative array that doesnt. a typical element in $pms array = $pms = array(
      array('index' => '1', 'name' => 'Edmund Barton', 'from' => '1 January 1901', 'to' => '24 September 1903', 'party' => 'Protectionist', 'duration' => '2 years, 8 months, 24 days', 'state' => 'New South Wales'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```
@if(is_object($pms) || is_array($pms))
@foreach($pms as $pm) 
              <tr><td>{{$pm['index']}}</td><td>{{$pm['name']}}</td><td>{{$pm['from']}}</td></tr>
            @endforeach

@endif
```

**Note**: Might be your $pms is not array OR object

Comment: thanks. although i didnt just the methods, i debugged and found that indeed my array was coming empty due to a logical error. the code was correct